# AxiosError: Network Error at XMLHttpRequest.handleError

Tags: python, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, axios

I'm trying to make a call for a prediction in a model I have deployed in the Google Cloud Platform. I have checked the logs in the Cloud Functions and when I send a file through my frontend, it finished with a status code 200 (there are no issues). When I try to upload the file, it seems my program isn't retrieving the prediction/result. I am using ReactJS for my frontend. This is for an image classification project.

Here is the relevant code snippet

```
const sendFile = useCallback(async () => {
        if (image) {
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", selectedFile);
            
            let res = await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL, formData);

            if (res.status === 200) {
                setData(res.data);
            }
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    },[image, selectedFile]);
```

I have a file '.env' that contains my endpoint (* is just to mask my ID)
`REACT_APP_API_URL='https://us-central1-future-graph-*****.cloudfunctions.net/predict'`

Here is the error produced

```
Network Error
AxiosError: Network Error
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49889:14)
```

Please if anyone knows a solution, that would greatly appreciated

I am unsure on how to approach this being a beginner in ReactJS.

Comment: What is the HTTP error code? Try to clarify your question as I do not understand what you are trying to do. Yes, I understand you are trying to upload a file, but beyond that everything is a mystery.